# keep getting this User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile while calling Google Analytics Reporting API V4

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, analytics

I study somewhere it is possible we can get DAU data from firebase google analytics, i want fetch data (DAU) of google analytics, and i am using Google Analytics Reporting API, for fetching data from firebase google analytics , i am calling this api from postman , and i am using this curl in postman:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345&start-date=2022-01-01&end-date=2022-01-31&metrics=ga:sessions" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {oauth2-token}"
```

Also i don't know from where i can get this ids=ga:1234, i tried different things here like property id, accound id etc, i study somewhere we can use view id here , i am unable to find view id.
and i am getting this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i have tried Google Analytics Reporting API to fetching dynamically  data of daily active users.
any other api or solution exist to get this DAU from firebase google analytics using rest api.
Maybe it is possible through bigQuery i want to avoid this approach.

Comment: Hey @Sohail Anwar did you try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929070/12892707

Comment: @IKRAMULHAQ, i tried this but due to limitation of documentation, i didn't understand how i can use this in flutter, also i am unable to find curl of this api.